# comparing hash element to table element perl

Tags: perl, optimization, hash

I have a program that compares each line of two files, each line contains one word, if simply read the two files and stock the data into table, and compare the element of the two tables,
the first file contain:
straight

```
work 

week 

belief time 

saturday 

wagon

australia

sunday 

french 
...
```

and the second file contain

```
firepower         

malaise         

bryson         

wagon         

dalglish 

french
...
```

this will take a long time to compare file, so I propose another solution, but this doesn't work

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open( FIC,  $ARGV[0] );
open( FICC, $ARGV[1] );

print "choose the name of the file\n";

chomp( my $fic2 = <STDIN> );
open( FIC2, ">$fic2" );
my $i=0;
my $j=0;
my @b=();
my %stops;
while (<FIC>)    #read each line into $_
{
    # Remove newline from $_
    chomp;
    $_ =~ s/\s+$//;
    $stops{$_} = $i;    # add the line to
    $i++;
}

close FIC;

while (<FICC>) {
    my $ligne = $_;
    $ligne =~ s/\s+$//;
    $b[$i] = lc($ligne);

    # $b contain the data

    $i++;
}

foreach my $che (@b) {

    chomp($che);

    print FIC2 $che;
    print FIC2 " ";

    print FIC2 $stops{"$che"}; print FIC2 "\n";

    #this returns nothing

}
```

The problem is in`this command  $stop{"$che"};` in the case that the elment don't exist in the hash %stop, it return an integer and an error

Use of initalized value in print c:/ats2/hash.pl line 44,  line 185B2

Comment: What is your input data? What is your output data? Your code doesn't work so tell as what you want to do instead of your broken code. Show us [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)!

Comment: each line contain a word, i use a hash to optimise my code, because it is very slow if i use tow tables

Comment: You are not helping, show an example of input data and desired output. Which part of [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) don't you understand?

Comment: Global symbol "$i" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $i"?) at - line 19.
Global symbol "$i" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $i"?) at - line 20.
Global symbol "@b" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my @b"?) at - line 28.
Global symbol "$i" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $i"?) at - line 28.
Global symbol "$i" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $i"?) at - line 32.
Global symbol "@b" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my @b"?) at ...

Comment: What do you mean by _compare the elements_? We can only guess. Is it whether “… they are the same” or “… all in $file1 are also in $file2” or “… some of them are in $file2” or “… have equal number of vowels in them” or WHAT?

Comment: i compare line by line, and word by word

Comment: I give up. It would be easier if you'd ask “I'm comparing tandoori chicken to dal makhani, ingredient by ingredient. What's wrong?”

Comment: @ChediBechikh: Look, you didn't show us original slow but working code. You show code which doesn't work or even compiles. You refuse to show us example input and desired output. You are talking in riddles. I don't know if it is some sort of joke or trolling but I ask you for the third time for [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I can guess what you would like but I like to know. You clearly don't let us know.

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil: i edited the code as you suggested and it work now, the only probelm is that in the case an element is not contained in the hash , the code will retrun an integer

Comment: @ChediBechikh: I don't see any common word in your example input and I also don't see any desired output.

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil: sorry i choose a bad example,but the tow file contain similar words, i correct the example

Comment: Your FIC loop leaves `$i` with a value equal to the number of lines in your FIC file, e.g. let's say `$i=20` when it has 20 lines.
Within your FICC loop you put the lines you read into the array `@b` **starting at `$b[20]`**.
This gives the first 20 elements in `@b` a value of `undef`, and that is what you get in the `foreach` loop.
Set `$i=0;` right before your FICC loop.

Answer (score 0):

Does this what you want?

```
join <(sort file1) <(sort file2) >result
```

Works in `bash`.

Comment: i edit the question, so the problem is in the $stops{"line"}, if it is not defined in the hash, i want to not show the result